# How to play encrypted video in flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am developing e tutor app using flutter so video have to be encrypt  so I encrypted all video and how can I play them in just my app only in offline mode from my SD card I used path provider?

Answer (score 1):

Using [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) package, you can encrypt or decrypt files in required format.
Just check it out, it might help.

Comment: but user can see decrypted file so it can be share

Answer (score 0):

The native exoplayer supports playing encrypted file. This also suits your requirement of not decrypting the file in external storage to prevent access.

Code Reference :
https://github.com/kimliss/myblog/blob/ffaf51b0269124809bc465ed8cdfa562e5a3c660/code/android/examples/exoplay/src/main/java/cn/todev/exoplay/MainActivity.kt

Code sample from above reference:

```
    val player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
    playerView.player = player

    // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
    val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "cn.todev"))

    val baseDataSource = dataSourceFactory.createDataSource()
    val decryptDataSource = AesCipherDataSource("ENCRYPTION_KEY".toByteArray(), baseDataSource)

    val videoSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory { decryptDataSource }
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(encryptPath))

    // Prepare the player with the source.
    player.prepare(videoSource)
```

Comment: please a little help i use flutter video player so how can achieve this via video player tanx

Comment: Hmmm. The video player of flutter does not expose this api I guess otherwise it would have been achievable. I'm hosting exoplayer in native activity and invoke the code from flutter.